# canonical links in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, canonical-link

All of the following lead to the same homepage of my site:

/
/news/
/news/all-time/all
/news/all-time/all/1

the same .cshtml file will also render other variations, e.g (the number on the end is the page number)

/news/month/all/
/news/month/images/3

im setting it in the view using something like : `ViewBag.CanonicalLink = "http://www.exmple.com/";`

etc..

now im trying to create a canonical link within the cshtml file, but puzzled with how to set it correctly for SEO? any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You should decide on a single canonical URL and then add `<link rel="canonical" href="...">` to the head.

Comment: the main link i want is "http://www.mysite.com/" but given that this page also renders for something like "http://www.mysite.com/news/month/images/3" then that wouldnt be apropriate to set it for that

Comment: @raklos: You should set the canonical URL to the URL you want to remain primary.  (and make sure that it's not a temporary url - make sure it won't change)